# Love2D Lua error: attempt to call field 'isDown' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, love2d

This is my code in Love2D:

```
function love.load()   
    ninja = love.graphics.newImage("Ninja.png")
    x = 0
    y = 0
    speed = 256
end

function love.update(dt)
    if love.keyboard.isDown("right") then
        ninja = love.graphics.newImage("NinjaRight.png")
        x = x + (speed * dt)
    end

    if love.keyboard.isDown("left") then
        ninja = love.graphics.newImage("NinjaLeft.png")
        x = x - (speed * dt)
    end

    if love.keyboard.isDown("down") then
        y = y + (speed * dt)
    end

    if love.keyboard.isDown("up") then
        y = y - (speed * dt)
    end

    if love.joystick.isDown(joystick, 1, 2, 3, 4) then
        a = 5
    end
end


function love.draw()
    love.graphics.draw(ninja, x, y)
end
```

I want to make the game to recognize a controller when connected.
But when I run the game, I receive the error:

> attempt to call field 'isDown'(a nil value)

Where is the problem?

Comment: What version of love are you using?

Comment: Because since `LÖVE 0.9.0` it was moved to `Joystick::isDown()` and available since `0.7.2`. Source: https://love2d.org/wiki/love.joystick.isDown

Comment: I am using Love 0.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `LÖVE 0.9.0` Joystick related `isDown()` function is moved to another `namespace`/`table`/You name ir or more "object" like structure. [1]

So, in Your code You should use it something like this:

```
--Get table of all connected Joysticks:
local joysticks = love.joystick.getJoysticks()

--Pick first one:
local joystick = joysticks[1]

if joystick:isDown(1, 2, 3, 4) then
    a = 5
end
```

Where `joystick` is Your `Joystick` object. [2]

Be aware, [love.keyboard.isDown()](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.keyboard.isDown) usage haven't changed yet. But, I guess, it's about to too. Sooner or later.

[1] https://love2d.org/wiki/Joystick:isDown

[2] https://love2d.org/wiki/love.joystick.getJoysticks

Comment: @Stucky, cool ^_^  so, could You please accept it as an answer to mark this question as answered one?